# Inverse of densely defined operator

Tags: functional-analysis

For given $0 \neq\lambda_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ let $T:\mathscr{D}(T) \not\subseteq H\rightarrow H$ be defined by
$$
Tx=\lambda_0 x.
$$
Find its inverse.

What I've done is the following.

Let $S:H\rightarrow H$ be defined by
$$
Sx=\lambda_0^{-1} x.
$$
Then $S$ is an bounded inverse of $T$. Indeed let $x\in\mathscr{D}(S)=H$ then
$$
TS x = \lambda_0 \lambda_0^{-1} x = I x,
$$
so $\mathscr{R}(S)=\mathscr{D}(T)$. It follows
that $\mathscr{D}(TS)=\mathscr{D}(S)=H$ and $\mathscr{D}(ST) = \mathscr{D}(T)$,
so $\mathscr{D}(ST) \subset \mathscr{D}(TS)$.

For $x\in\mathscr{D}(T)$ we have
$$
ST x = \lambda_0^{-1} \lambda_0 x = \lambda_0 \lambda_0^{-1} x = TS x = I x.
$$
Thus $ST \subset TS = I$ and the boundedness follows from $\|S\|=|\lambda_0^{-1}|$.

My question is if I can define $S$ as I did.

Comment: $\lambda_0 \ne 0$, right?  The assumption is tacit in your references to $\lambda_0^{-1}$, but maybe making explicit would help.

Comment: @RobertLewis indeed. I edited the question.